# Transferring data to another server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple app where 200 people registered via facebook or normal email login. I wrote another version of the same app and deployed it to another server with higher RAM.

How do I transfer the user data like login creds to new server? I used Devise gem(if that helps).

PS: My database design also changed a lot.

Comment: dump the database. Then export it as a sql file. Then import the sql file in a new database in the newly created server.

Comment: @Emu I have updated my question. The thing is that my database has changed a lot too.

Comment: But your `User` table remains same for both the server, right? So, if you export/mport the database will create the User table with data, then you can migrate the new server database for applying changes. 
Or, you can write a script to create CSV for the user table, then r/w the csv file in newly created db.

Answer (score 0):

Devise Gem uses DB to store the encrypted credentials.  You would need to migrate the Database if the new machine also has a new DB.  But if you are only migrating the application, then you can directly point to the same DB and things should work as they are.

Comment: but does not the encrypted creds depend upon secret key or something?

Comment: The secret key configuration is stored in the application.  It might be of format `config.secret_key = 'my_super_secret_key'`